# How do I set a new default Team in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

On our Team Foundation Server, the **default team** for our project is set to a team that was removed/deleted.

This results in the error: `The default team for project id 
'<Project Name>' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.`

How do we change the default team to a team that does exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the VSTS Web Portal, go to "Settings\Overview", click "..." button on the team, there is a "Set team as project default" option.
[image]

Comment: I'm glad that there is an easier way. Can you find any documentation on it?

Comment: Does anybody know if this changes the default team for the logged in user or for ALL users in the project?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to set the *default team* via the Team Foundation Server Client Library which you can obtain from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/).

It uses the `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamService.SetDefaultTeam()` API described on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.client.tfsteamservice.setdefaultteam.aspx).

You can use the following PowerShell script after substituting in the correct values.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll")
$uri= "http://tfs:8080/tfs/ESGCollection"
$tpc= New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection-ArgumentList "http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection"
$teamService= $tpc.GetService([type]'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamService')
$teams= $teamService.QueryTeams("45e4d731-3ff9-4064-b6ca-ef5aafe31337")# the Team Project ID
$teamService.SetDefaultTeam($teams[0])
```